# In GWT, How to use custom widget tag in an .ui.xml file with and without parameters for the tag in the same file

Tags: gwt, uibinder, custom-widgets

I am creating a custom widget, say "CustomWid" in UiBinder.
And in CustomWid.java file I am writing two constructors 
    one with zero args like
`CustomWid(){....}`

```
 another with some args like
```

`CustomWid(String a,String b){......}`
So,Now I am using my custom widget in another .ui.xml file,in that .ui.xml file
   it is working fine when we give
    `<my:CustomWid/>`     alone,
   and also fine when we give like
 `<my:CustomWid a="srt1" b="str2"/>`         alone
But "MY PROBLEM" is whenever I am trying to give both the tags in the one .ui.xml as
`<my:CustomWid/>
    <my:CustomWid a="str1" b="str2"/>`

   Now it is throwing error when i am using both types of tags in a single .ui.xml
I mean How to use my custom widget tag like a prdefined tag?
I am using `@uiConstructor`, but it showing error
Please developers... I need answer as early as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UiBinder will only ever use a single constructor for a given widget: either its zero-arg constructor, or a `@UiConstructor` (I'm surprised that you say it works when using either one or the other *call* but not both: one should fail in every case, and one should succeed in every case; if you haven't annotated a constructor with `@UiConstructor`, then `<my:CustomWid/>` should always work and `<my:CustomWid a="str1" b="str2"/>` should always fail)

There are two solutions here:

- use setters for the `a` and `b` attributes (`void setA(String a)` and `void setB(String b)`)), and possibly check later (say, in `onLoad` or `onAttach`) that you have either none or both of A and B, but not one without the other (if that's your rule).
- use `@UiField(provided = true)` when you need to use the *other* constructor (if you choose to have UiBinder use the zero-arg constructor –i.e. no `@UiConstructor`–, then that means you'll have to move the `a="str1" b="str2"` from the XML to the Java code: `@UiField(provided = true) CustomWid myCustomWid = new CustomWid("str1", "str2")`).

The first option has my preference.

Comment: So, if you are correct..then How the GWT team is making widgets like <HorizontalPanel/> and also it is possible to include <HorizontalPanel width="100px"/> in the same file.So How they are acheving it.....Please Explain If you are familiar with this concept

Comment: `CellPanel`s (`HorizontalPanel` and `VerticalPanel`) have a special _parser_. There's however no extension point to make your own parser for your widgets.

Comment: Note: I added `@UiField(provided = true)` as an alternative in my answer, for completeness; I think you already knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

It Will not show any errors...'

```
  @UiConstructor
  public Component(String displayText,String heading)
      {
 initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

  this.displayText.setText(displayText);
    this.heading.setText(heading);  
    }`
```

now use another constructor with default parameters also it will work 

         `public Component()
        {
      initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
          }`
         now if you add with xml parameters component and without parameters also works in the same page.